# Is there a variant of Thompson Sampling that works with variable bandits?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, multi-armed-bandits, thompson-sampling

Does there exist a variant of TS, such that, while computing the returns of multi-armed bandits, we have the possibility of introducing an extra bandit?

For instance, while we are applying TS to 3 slot machines, we come to know about the existence of a fourth slot machine. Therefore, we'd like to take that machine into account within our algorithm.

Comment: So, are you asking about applying TS to bandit problems with a variable/dynamic number of actions?

Comment: Yes, that’s what I am asking.